# Access package_id from resource dict in CKAN

Tags: api, resources, package, action, ckan

I'm looking for a way to find the package_id for a resource in CKAN. I access the resource via the `resource_show` action:

```
resource_dict = toolkit.get_action("resource_show")(context, {"id": "my-resource"})
```

The resulting dict does not tell me what package the resource belongs to. It does tell me:

```
resource_dict.get("package_id", None) == None # <<< True
resource_dict["resource_group_id"] = "some-uuid"
```

And I can see in my database that a `resource_group` does have a `package_id` attribute. However, there doesn't seem to be a `resource_group_show` action.

Is there another way for me to navigate from a resource dict to its parent package?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In CKAN 2.3 and newer, `package_id` is returned in the call to the `resource_show` API call.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, unfortunately the current version of CKAN (2.2.1) doesn't include the package_id when you call resource_show, and there is no resource_group_show call.  If you are writing an extension, you can get around this by performing a direct database query:

```
SELECT resource_group.package_id
  FROM resource, resource_group
 WHERE resource.id='<resource_id>' AND
       resource.resource_group_id=resource_group.id;
```

If you're trying to get the package_id using the API, the only way to find it is to search from the top down, calling package_list, then package_show for each until you find the one containing the pertinent resource_id.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `revision_show` method.

```
import ckanapi

ckan = ckanapi.RemoteCKAN('url', apikey='key')    
resource = ckan.action.resource_show(id='resource_id')
revision_id = resource['revision_id']
revision = ckan.action.revision_show(id=revision_id)
package_id = revision['packages'][0]
```